How does the Laplace operator act on a functional determinant?
Consider the functional $n \times n$ matrix
$$
D_n = \begin{pmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} & \ldots & f_{1,n}\\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & \ldots & f_{2,n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\
f_{n,1} & f_{n,2} & \ldots & f_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $f_{i,j}$ are differentiable functions of the variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$.
The partial derivatives $\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ act so nicely on the determinant of the matrix $D_n$
$$
\partial_i \left( \begin{vmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} & \ldots & f_{1,n}\\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & \ldots & f_{2,n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\
f_{n,1} & f_{n,2} & \ldots & f_{n,n}
\end{vmatrix} \right) = \begin{vmatrix} \partial_i(f_{1,1}) & \partial_i(f_{1,2}) & \ldots & \partial_i(f_{1,n}) \\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & \ldots & f_{2,n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\
f_{n,1} & f_{n,2} & \ldots & f_{n,n}
\end{vmatrix} + \cdots + \begin{vmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} & \ldots & f_{1,n}\\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & \ldots & f_{2,n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\
\partial_i(f_{n,1}) & \partial_i(f_{n,2}) & \ldots & \partial_i(f_{n,n})
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
I am interested in the action of the Laplace operator
$$\Delta_n = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2} + \cdots + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_n^2},$$
on the determinant of the matrix $D_n$.
Of course, since $\Delta_n$ is not merely derivation, its action will not be as straightforward. However, the following examples for $n=2,3$ gives hope that the deviation of its action from derivations is not very significant: direct computation can show that
$$
\Delta_2 \left( \begin{vmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} \\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2}
\end{vmatrix}  \right)= \begin{vmatrix} \Delta_2(f_{1,1}) & \Delta_2(f_{1,2}) \\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2}
\end{vmatrix} +\begin{vmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} \\
\Delta_2(f_{2,1}) & \Delta_2(f_{2,2})
\end{vmatrix} +2 \begin{vmatrix} \partial_1( f_{1,1}) & \partial_1(f_{1,2}) \\
\partial_1(f_{2,1}) & \partial_1(f_{2,2})
\end{vmatrix}+2 \begin{vmatrix} \partial_2( f_{1,1}) & \partial_2(f_{1,2}) \\
\partial_2(f_{2,1}) & \partial_2(f_{2,2})
\end{vmatrix}
$$
and \begin{gather*}
\Delta_3 \left( \begin{vmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} & f_{1,3} \\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & f_{2,3}\\
f_{3,1} & f_{3,2} & f_{3,3}\\
\end{vmatrix}  \right)=\begin{vmatrix} \Delta_3(f_{1,1}) & \Delta_3(f_{1,2}) & \Delta_3(f_{1,3}) \\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & f_{2,3}\\
f_{3,1} & f_{3,2} & f_{3,3}\\
\end{vmatrix} +\begin{vmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} & f_{1,3} \\
\Delta_3(f_{2,1}) & \Delta_3(f_{2,2}) & \Delta_3(f_{2,3})\\
f_{3,1} & f_{3,2} & f_{3,3}\\
\end{vmatrix} +\\ \\ +\begin{vmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} & f_{1,3} \\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & f_{2,3}\\
\Delta_3(f_{3,1}) & \Delta_3(f_{3,2}) & \Delta_3(f_{3,3})\\
\end{vmatrix} +\color{red}{2\,\begin{vmatrix} \partial_1(f_{1,1}) & \partial_1(f_{1,2}) & \partial_1(f_{1,3}) \\
\partial_1(f_{2,1}) & \partial_1(f_{2,2}) & \partial_1(f_{2,3})\\
f_{3,1} & f_{3,2} & f_{3,3}\\
\end{vmatrix}+ 2\,\begin{vmatrix} \partial_2(f_{1,1}) & \partial_2(f_{1,2}) & \partial_2(f_{1,3}) \\
\partial_2(f_{2,1}) & \partial_2(f_{2,2}) & \partial_2(f_{2,3})\\
f_{3,1} & f_{3,2} & f_{3,3}\\
\end{vmatrix}+\\ \\ + 2\,\begin{vmatrix} \partial_3(f_{1,1}) & \partial_3(f_{1,2}) & \partial_3(f_{1,3}) \\
\partial_3(f_{2,1}) & \partial_3(f_{2,2}) & \partial_3(f_{2,3})\\
f_{3,1} & f_{3,2} & f_{3,3}\\
\end{vmatrix}+ 2\,\begin{vmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} & f_{1,3} \\
\partial_1(f_{2,1} & \partial_1(f_{2,2}) & \partial_1(f_{2,3})\\
\partial_1(f_{3,1}) & \partial_1(f_{3,2}) & \partial_1(f_{3,3})\\
\end{vmatrix}  +  2\,\begin{vmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} & f_{1,3} \\
\partial_2(f_{2,1} & \partial_2(f_{2,2}) & \partial_2(f_{2,3})\\
\partial_2(f_{3,1}) & \partial_2(f_{3,2}) & \partial_2(f_{3,3})\\
\end{vmatrix} +\\ \\ + 2\,\begin{vmatrix} f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} & f_{1,3} \\
\partial_3(f_{2,1} & \partial_3(f_{2,2}) & \partial_3(f_{2,3})\\
\partial_3(f_{3,1}) & \partial_3(f_{3,2}) & \partial_3(f_{3,3})\\
\end{vmatrix} + 2\,\begin{vmatrix} \partial_1(f_{1,1}) & \partial_1(f_{1,2}) & \partial_1(f_{1,3}) \\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & f_{2,3}\\
\partial_1(f_{3,1}) & \partial_1(f_{3,2}) & \partial_1(f_{3,3})\\
\end{vmatrix}+ 2\,\begin{vmatrix} \partial_2(f_{1,1}) & \partial_2(f_{1,2}) & \partial_2(f_{1,3}) \\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & f_{2,3}\\
\partial_2(f_{3,1}) & \partial_2(f_{3,2}) & \partial_2(f_{3,3})\\
\end{vmatrix} +\\ \\ + 2\,\begin{vmatrix} \partial_3(f_{1,1}) & \partial_3(f_{1,2}) & \partial_3(f_{1,3}) \\
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & f_{2,3}\\
\partial_3(f_{3,1}) & \partial_1(f_{3,2}) & \partial_1(f_{3,3})
\end{vmatrix}}.
\end{gather*}
Unfortunately, with this approach, the long red tail of the formula will only continue to grow.
Question. Since the Laplacian operator is well-studied, is there a known good  formula for
$\Delta_n (|D_n|)$ when $n > 3?$

The determinant is the sum over all  products with signed index permutation  $\sigma\in \mathit S_n$ $$\det f = \sum_{\sigma\in \mathit S_n} \ \text{sig}(\sigma) f_{1,\sigma(1)}\dots f_{n,\sigma(n)} $$
$$ \partial_{kk} \det f   =  \sum_{\sigma\in \mathit S_n} \ \text{sig}(\sigma) \ \sum_l \frac{\partial_{kk}  f_{l,\sigma(l)}}{ f_{l,\sigma(l)}} \ f_{1,\sigma(1)} \dots f_{n,\sigma(n))}  
$$ $$+ \sum_{\sigma\in \mathit S_n} \ \text{sig}(\sigma)  \ \sum_{l\ne m} \frac{\partial_{k}  f_{l,\sigma(l)}}{f_{l,\sigma(l)}} \ \frac{\partial_{k}  f_{m,\sigma(m)})}{ f_{m,\sigma(m)}} \ f_{1,\sigma(1)} \dots f_{n,\sigma(n))}$$

I am looking for a nice determinant explicit formula
